# How to continue your code after an if else statement without breaking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods

I am approximating the error for a numerical mathematical method but after I wrote my if else statement the code seems to endlessly continue in that statement unless I break it. but I want to continue the simulation using the code underneath to finish the second part of the approximation. any suggestions?

```
while True:
        m1 = h*func1(t,v, Hs)
        k1 = h*func2(t,v, Hs)

        m2 = h*func1(t+(h/2),v+(m1/2), Hs + (k1/2))
        k2= h*func2(t+(h/2),v+(m1/2), Hs +(k1/2))

        m3 = h*func1(t+(h/2),v+(m2/2),Hs+(k2/2))
        k3= h*func2(t+(h/2),v+(m2/2),Hs+(k2/2))

        m4 = h*func1(t+h,v+m3,Hs+k3)
        k4= h*func2(t+h,v+m3,Hs+k3)

        v= v +(1/6)*(m1+(2*m2)+(2*m3)+m4)
        Hs=Hs + (1/6)*(k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4)
        t= t+h
        if Hs > 11: 
            f = f +0.0001
            Hs=Hr*d/(L*f+d)
            v = math.sqrt(2*g*Hr*d/(L*f+d))
            t = 0

        else: 
        break


while (t2 <= 10):
    m12 = z*func1(t2,v2,Hs2)
    k12 = z*func2(t2,v2,Hs2)

    m22 = z*func1(t2+(z/2),v2+(m12/2), Hs2 + (k12/2))
    k22= z*func2(t2+(z/2),v2+(m12/2), Hs2 +(k12/2))

    m32 = z*func1(t2+(z/2),v2+(m22/2),Hs2+(k22/2))
    k32= z*func2(t2+(z/2),v2+(m22/2),Hs2+(k22/2))

    m42 = z*func1(t2+z,v2+m32,Hs2+k32)
    k42= z*func2(t2+z,v2+m32,Hs2+k32)

    v2= v2 +(1/6)*(m12+(2*m22)+(2*m32)+m42)
    Hs2=Hs2 + (1/6)*(k12+(2*k22)+(2*k32)+k42)
    t2 =t2+z


    if t2 == 10:break
```

after Hs reaches < 11 for a certain f, the program continues until it is endlessly large. But after t has achieved a value of 75 I want the code to continue with the while loop written underneath.

Comment: What "continues endlessly"? The `while` loop? There's no looping other than that.

Comment: yes but what i am trying to indicate is that when i break it after the if statement it wont keep returning the f+0.001

Comment: how is it possible to break it while making sure that the code continues somehow

Comment: An if statement executes only once unless it's in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `continue` statement in python.
For example:

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
>>>     if i == 3:
>>>         continue
>>>     print(i)

0
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

As you can see the `3` is missing because the `continue` statement continued when `i` was `3`.

It didn't stop the loop, it just continued with the `4`.

I think this could help.